# How to fix ssl certificate has expired (_ssl.s:1002)

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

While fetching the MNIST dataset from `sklearn`, I got the following error message:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1002)>
```

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an SSL certificate has expired on the server, so you may have to wait for the MNIST server to get their SSL certificate renewed again.
You could also check if your time & date are set correctly and try updating the certifi package, through `pip install --upgrade certifi`. Or just bypass the SSL verification error (note: this could open you to security risks)

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, as_frame=False)
```

Comment: I tried updating the certifi package and got a message that requirement was already satisfied. When I reran the code, including the "as_frame=False," I got the same error message.

Comment: Can you access the site itself? The site's SSL certificate may have expired